# MSVC++ 2013 Debug vs. Release Compiling Issue

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-studio-2013, calling-convention

So I am experimenting with how to call C++ programs from ASM. It works on debug mode, but not so much on release mode.

I have assembly code that looks like this :

```
sub rsp, 30h
mov rcx, 1
mov rdx, 2
mov r8, 3
mov r9, 4
mov qword ptr [rsp + 20h], 5
mov qword ptr [rsp + 28h], 6
call MyProc
add rsp, 30h
ret
```

And the MyProc function looks like this :

```
extern "C"
{
    *other irrelevant methods here*

    void MyProc(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f)
    {
        cout << "First & Last Param : " << a << " and " << f << endl;
    }
}
```

In debug mode, it runs properly. On release mode, it fails with : `Error 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`

Whats going on, and how do I fix this?

Comment: Step thru it in the debugger and see for yourself.  What optimizations are being used in the release build?

Comment: How are you initializing the c runtime?  Normally this is done for you before calling a c program's 'main' function, but if your entry point for the program is asm, you must do this yourself.

Comment: You are mis-aligning the stack, causing an alignment fault on a SIMD instruction.  It must be `sub rsp, 38h`.

Comment: @Hans Passant I would upvote your answer and mark it as correct but on my screen, it mysteriously disappeared :P

Comment: Just post the answer yourself and accept it to close your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimenting, all I need to do is to sub the stack pointer by any number greater or equal than the (number of parameters of the function * 8) bytes, but the number has to end with an 8 to keep the stack aligned (credit to Hans), so numbers like 28h for (< 5 param), 38h(6 - 7 param), 48h (8 - 9 param) etc. would work.

Not sure if I'm wrong about this, but the first 4 bytes of the stack are reserved, which is why I need to sub the stack by more than 32 bytes...

Answer (score 0):

You can see example of calling c++ function from ASM(exactly what you want to do) here:
[how to use a library in masm or more specifcally a .lib file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23550203/how-to-use-a-library-in-masm-or-more-specifcally-a-lib-file)

But I guess you problem is from Optimizations that is used for Release mode. Because when Optimizations are enabled for your library, you must adjust your assembly code to work properly with that optimized library.

Let's see your case.

Here are 2 files:

**lib.c**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern "C"
{
    void MyProc(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f)
    {
        cout << "First & Last Param : " << a << " and " << f << endl;
    }
}
```

**test.asm**

```
includelib source.lib
MyProc PROTO a:QWORD, b:QWORD, c:QWORD, d:QWORD, e:QWORD, f:QWORD

.CODE

    main PROC

    sub rsp, 30h
    mov rcx, 1
    mov rdx, 2
    mov r8, 3
    mov r9, 4
    mov qword ptr [rsp + 20h], 5
    mov qword ptr [rsp + 28h], 6
    call MyProc
    add rsp, 30h
    ret

    main ENDP

END
```

now I try compile and link both. first without any optimization:

```
cl /c lib.c
lib lib.obj
ml64 test.asm /link /subsystem:console
```

in this case code will run correctly. But now if you enable any optimization for library:

```
cl /c /O2 lib.c
lib lib.obj
ml64 test.asm /link /subsystem:console
```

your code will not run correctly anymore.

Comment: At first I had a hunch that it had something to do with optimization, because when I changed it to an arithmetic instruction it ran on both debug and release, but when stepping through the assembly, the Release version had only a `ret` instruction. I'll look at it more when I get home.

Comment: you should check Hans answer too. it is important. after correcting that 30h to 38h, everything works correctly even with optimization too.